# 14.04 Shutdown hangs on printing error message

Tags: 14.04, shutdown

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. When it shuts down, it would print out many error messages, and hang.

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot is hard to read, did you take the picture once it was stuck or while it was printing errors?!

Comment: @AlexisWilke It's running so fast that I cannot capture a stable image.

Comment: Ah, I see, it hangs in a forever loop... At times Ctrl-S still works, but I would be surprised because by then it probably has no console functionality anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The one reason for my shutdown to hang is because my nVidea video board driver will get blocked, although when that happens I do not see any messages.

In any event, here it says that it has a problem with PCIe Port 0000:00:1c.6 so we would need to know what's connected on that port to get a better feel of what the kernel does not like.

You can see what it is with an `lspci` command in your console after a reboot. In my case, it is an Intel Bridge:

```
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 7 (rev 06)
```

It seems to say that it is the same on your computer (i.e. it says it is a bus). It could be that you have a video board that it does not like...

Comment: This answer is very vague. As you do not really provide any sure solution, in my opinion this would have better been a comment only. Or you reword it to be more definite.

Comment: If we can get info on his hardware that matches what I'm saying, we're possibly on the right track. We would need the output of his `lspci`. That being said, there are times when a comment is ill adapted to give clear examples of output or commands, in my point of view.